# Java unreachable code error

Tags: java

I was following a tutorial on youtube and when I got to the part where I'm supposed to use "this.path" and things like that, however I seem to be getting errors. I can't seem to find any solution to this.

Here is a link to the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7pfq0W3e4I

```
package gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {

public String path;
public int width;
public int height;

public int[] pixels;


public SpriteSheet(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
image =     ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    if(image == null);{
        return;
    }


    this.path = path;
    this.width = image.getWidth();
    this.height = image.getHeight();    

    pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

    for(int i = 0; i <= pixels.length;i++){
        pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xff)/64;
    }


    for(int i = 0;i <= 8;i++) {
        System.out.println(pixels[i]);
    }


}       
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 7):

Your error is here:

```
if(image == null);{
    return;
}
```

You have an additional semicolon after the `if` statement. This should instead be:

```
if(image == null) {
    return;
}
```

The semicolon ends the if statement; in other words, `if(image == null)`, do nothing, then run `return;`

Java does not allow unreachable code. Since your `return` statement is being run regardless of the if-condition, anything past that point cannot be reached.